# How to SSH into a server and then SFTP from there to another server?

Tags: ruby, net-ssh, net-sftp

Here's the situation:

I have SSH access to ServerA

I have SFTP access to ServerB, but only from ServerA

I want to use Ruby to SSH into ServerA, then SFTP files from ServerB to ServerA.

I can connect to ServerA using the documentation from Net::SSH:

```
require 'net/ssh/gateway'

gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('server_a', 'user')

gateway.ssh("server_a", "user") do |ssh|
  # how to SFTP into server_b here and run SFTP commands?
end

gateway.shutdown!
```

What I can't figure out is how to SFTP into ServerB from the context of ServerA?

Comment: I don't think you can do this using only code running on the local machine -- I think you're going to need to initiate the A->B connection with code running on A.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your private keys setup, run:

```
$ ssh-add
```

And write something like this:

```
require 'net/ssh'

# Set :forward_agent => true so that it will automatically authenticate with server_b
Net::SSH.start('server_a', 'user', :forward_agent => true) do |ssh|
  puts ssh.exec!("scp -r server_b:dir_i_want_to_copy dir_to_copy_to/")
end
```

Comment: Not sure if scp will work, as I only have (S)FTP access to server_b

Answer (score 1):

You can declare scp method in Net::SSH::Gateway class.

I have copied similar ssh method and it works fine.

```
    class Gateway < Net::SSH::Gateway
      def scp(host, user, options={}, &block)
        local_port = open(host, options[:port] || 22)

        begin
          Net::SCP.start("127.0.0.1", user, options.merge(:port => local_port), &block)
        ensure
          close(local_port) if block || $!
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the gateway library directly to net/sftp worked well for me:

```
class Net::SSH::Gateway
  def sftp(host, user, options={}, &block)
    local_port = open(host, options[:port] || 22)
    begin
      Net::SFTP.start("127.0.0.1", user, options.merge(:port => local_port), &block)
    ensure
      close(local_port) if block || $!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

from a  command line, you can specify a command to be executed on the server after SSH'ing into it

First google result: http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html

So you can imagine placing the ssh command in backticks in the Ruby code, then executing the SFTP command

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

`ssh myserver 'sftp another-server'`
```

Something to look into